# Stuck on the final bits of a multi series line chart

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I built a multi series Highcharts https://www.highcharts.com/ line chart with irregular time data. It's almost there, but I'm doing something wrong with the data and/or data formatting. Anyone have a hint or two to throw my way?

The date from the database was converted from '02/03/2009' to javascript time in php using 
$date = strtotime($data['As of Date'])*1000;

The other value is a dollar amount.

I haven't yet added the filtered data for 3MO, 6MO, 1YR, 5YR, 10YR

Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/madmichael/th41g4yt/

```
$( document ).ready(function() { 

            createChart();

            });


            function createChart(chartingOptions) {

                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'line',
                        zoomType: 'xy',
                        events: {
                            load: function(event) {
                                var total = 0; // get total of data
                                for (var i = 0, len = this.series[0].yData.length; i < len; i++) {
                                    total += this.series[0].yData[i];
                                }
                                var text = this.renderer.text(
                                    'Total: $' + Highcharts.numberFormat(total, 0, '.', ','),
                                    this.plotLeft,
                                    this.plotTop + 20
                                ).attr({
                                    zIndex: 5
                                }).add() // write it to the upper left hand corner
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    navigator: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    scrollbar: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    rangeSelector: {
                        inputEnabled: false,
                        allButtonsEnabled: true,
                        /* buttons: [[]], */
                        buttons: [
                        {
                            type: 'all',
                            text: 'All'
                        }, {
                            type: 'month',
                            count: 3,
                            text: '3MO'
                        }, {
                            type: 'month',
                            count: 6,
                            text: '6MO'
                        }, {
                            type: 'year',
                            text: '1YR',
                            count: 1
                        }, {
                            type: 'year',
                            text: '5YR',
                            count: 5
                        }, {
                            type: 'year',
                            text: '10YR',
                            count: 10
                        }],
                        buttonTheme: {
                            width: 60
                        },
                        selected: 0

                    },

                    tooltip: {
                        backgroundColor: null,
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        shadow: false,
                        useHTML: true,
                        style: {
                            padding: 0
                        },
                        pointFormat: '$' + '{point.y:,.0f}'
            /*              formatter: function() {
                            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %d, %Y', point.x) + ': $ 
            {point.y:,.1f}';
                        }   */      
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        type: 'datetime',
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function() {
                                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b-%Y', this.value);
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        type: 'linear',
                            labels: {
                                formatter: function () {
                                    if(this.value  >= 0 ){
                                        return '$' + this.value / 1000+'k';
                                    }else{
                                        return '-$' + this.value / 1000*-1+'k';
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    },
            series: [{name: 'Investment Fund (A)',fundtype: 'Load',data: [[1483164000000,37149],[1451541600000,37247],[1420005600000,37071],[1388469600000,33407],[1356933600000,19881],[1325311200000,14132],[1293775200000,21541],[1262239200000,18343],[1480485600000,36659],[1448863200000,39677],[1417327200000,38070],[1385791200000,32212],[1354255200000,18197],[1322632800000,14132],[1291096800000,20173],[1259560800000,17399],[1477890000000,34171],[1446267600000,39069],[1414731600000,36522],[1383195600000,30429],[1351659600000,18468],[1320037200000,14848],[1288501200000,20250],[1256965200000,15703],[1475211600000,36503],[1443589200000,36071],[1412053200000,34602],[1380517200000,29214],[1348981200000,17752],[1317358800000,13048],[1285822800000,19287],[1254286800000,17861],[1472619600000,35249],[1440997200000,38775],[1409461200000,36542],[1377925200000,27548],[1346389200000,16784],[1314766800000,15642],[1283230800000,16994],[1251694800000,16821],[1469941200000,32741],[1438318800000,42537],[1406782800000,34230],[1375246800000,28273],[1343710800000,16203],[1312088400000,17674],[1280552400000,18478],[1249016400000,14335],[1467262800000,29782],[1435640400000,40245],[1404104400000,36150],[1372568400000,26157],[1341032400000,16861],[1309410000000,19707],[1277874000000,17013],[1246338000000,13083],[1496206800000,41636],[1464670800000,33015],[1433048400000,40656],[1401512400000,34720],[1369976400000,26850],[1338440400000,16010],[1306818000000,20963],[1275282000000,19441],[1243746000000,12563],[1493528400000,40010],[1461992400000,32603],[1430370000000,39814],[1398834000000,33779],[1367298000000,25205],[1335762000000,17229],[1304139600000,21233],[1272603600000,21426],[1241067600000,10732],[1490936400000,39794],[1459400400000,33054],[1427778000000,39304],[1396242000000,34798],[1364706000000,24063],[1333170000000,17771],[1301547600000,21021],[1270011600000,20983],[1238475600000,8940],[1456725600000,30977],[1330495200000,17307],[1488261600000,40696],[1425103200000,39285],[1393567200000,34955],[1362031200000,22011],[1298872800000,21233],[1267336800000,19268],[1235800800000,7534],[1233640800000,9422],[1485842400000,37149],[1454220000000,30233],[1422684000000,35856],[1391148000000,33603],[1359612000000,22108],[1327989600000,15990],[1296453600000,21021],[1264917600000,18459]]},{name: 'Investment Fund (A)',fundtype: 'No Load',data: [[1483164000000,39428],[1451541600000,39532],[1420005600000,39345],[1388469600000,35456],[1356933600000,21101],[1325311200000,14999],[1293775200000,22863],[1262239200000,19468],[1480485600000,38908],[1448863200000,42111],[1417327200000,40406],[1385791200000,34188],[1354255200000,19314],[1322632800000,14999],[1291096800000,21411],[1259560800000,18466],[1477890000000,36267],[1446267600000,41466],[1414731600000,38763],[1383195600000,32295],[1351659600000,19601],[1320037200000,15759],[1288501200000,21493],[1256965200000,16667],[1475211600000,38742],[1443589200000,38284],[1412053200000,36725],[1380517200000,31006],[1348981200000,18841],[1317358800000,13848],[1285822800000,20470],[1254286800000,18957],[1472619600000,37411],[1440997200000,41154],[1409461200000,38784],[1377925200000,29238],[1346389200000,17814],[1314766800000,16601],[1283230800000,18037],[1251694800000,17853],[1469941200000,34749],[1438318800000,45147],[1406782800000,36330],[1375246800000,30008],[1343710800000,17197],[1312088400000,18759],[1280552400000,19611],[1249016400000,15215],[1467262800000,31609],[1435640400000,42714],[1404104400000,38368],[1372568400000,27762],[1341032400000,17896],[1309410000000,20916],[1277874000000,18057],[1246338000000,13885],[1496206800000,44190],[1464670800000,35040],[1433048400000,43151],[1401512400000,36850],[1369976400000,28498],[1338440400000,16992],[1306818000000,22249],[1275282000000,20634],[1243746000000,13333],[1493528400000,42464],[1461992400000,34604],[1430370000000,42256],[1398834000000,35851],[1367298000000,26751],[1335762000000,18286],[1304139600000,22536],[1272603600000,22740],[1241067600000,11391],[1490936400000,42236],[1459400400000,35082],[1427778000000,41716],[1396242000000,36933],[1364706000000,25539],[1333170000000,18862],[1301547600000,22311],[1270011600000,22270],[1238475600000,9489],[1456725600000,32878],[1330495200000,18368],[1488261600000,43192],[1425103200000,41695],[1393567200000,37099],[1362031200000,23361],[1298872800000,22536],[1267336800000,20450],[1235800800000,7996],[1233640800000,10000],[1485842400000,39428],[1454220000000,32087],[1422684000000,38056],[1391148000000,35664],[1359612000000,23464],
            [1327989600000,16971],[1296453600000,22311],[1264917600000,19591]]},],
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            events: {
                                show: function () {
                                    var chart = this.chart,
                                        series = chart.series,
                                        i = series.length,
                                        otherSeries;
                                    while (i--) {
                                        otherSeries = series[i];
                                        if (otherSeries != this && otherSeries.visible) 
            {
                                            otherSeries.hide();
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                legendItemClick: function() {
                                    if(this.visible){
                                         return false;   
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        line: {
                            marker: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
            /*                    color: '".$attributes["line_color"]."',
            */                }

                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: -150,
                        y: 100,
                        floating: true,
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && 
            Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                };

            /*        options.series[5] = {
                        name: '5 Yrs',
                        data: processed_five_years,
                        visible: false
                    };
            */
                var chart = new Highcharts.stockChart(options);
                Highcharts.setOptions({
                    lang: {
                        decimalPoint: '.',
                        thousandsSep: ','
                    }
                });



            };
```

Comment: Make sure your data is sorted in ascending order by `x` value.

Comment: According to error in the console (https://www.highcharts.com/errors/15) your data requires to be sorted by x asceding, like @jlbriggs metioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That got me back on track. I needed to sort the subdata sets using 


    `usort($fund_data_load['data'], function($a, $b) { return $a[0] - $b[0];  });`